# grpc-java how to get generic type from StreamObserver<V>

Tags: java, grpc

I want to write a aop to grpc interface method, how can i get generic type from StreamObserver

```
@Around(value = "execution(* com.test.grpc.controller.*.*(..))")
    public void around(ProceedingJoinPoint point) throws Throwable {

        long methodStartTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        String methodName = point.getSignature().getDeclaringTypeName() +
                "." + point.getSignature().getName();

        point.proceed();

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't, since it is generic.

I don't know enough about aop to provide alternatives.